# Remove specific item in a sequence in XQuery

Tags: xquery-3.1

What is a good way to remove a specific item in a sequence?

I want to remove "b" from the sequence ("a", "b", "c") for example.

```
("a", "b", "c")
-> do something
-> ("a", "c")
```

What I know does work is to split the sequence in two and then glue them back together but I would like to know if there are nicer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `$seq[. != 'b']` where `$seq` contains your sequence, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

`$seq[not(. eq 'b')]`, i.e., return items in the sequence, except for values of b. This approach avoids some of the vagaries of `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `('a', 'b', 'c')[. ne 'b']`